# Horizontal news slider in html css

Tags: css

I am making a latest news bar for a website. It needs to look like this:
[image]

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b648z1ve/1/). Please guide me how can I achieve the image like design. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="green">
Latest News
</div>
<div class="black">
Some text here

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.green{
    height:30px; 
    background-color:#3E6A56;
    color:#FFF;
    width:130px;
    float:left;  
}
.black{
    height:30px; 
    background-color:#000000; display:inline;
    float:right;
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/b648z1ve/2/

```
.green{
    height:30px; 
    background-color:#3E6A56;
    color:#FFF;
    width:130px;
    float:left;  
    width:30%;
}
.black{
    height:30px; 
    background-color:#000000; display:inline;
    float:right;
    color:#FFF;
    width:70%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Added and edited a little code -

```
.black{
    height:30px; 
    background-color:#000000; display:inline;
    float:right;
    color:#FFF;
    width:calc(100% - 130px);
}
.green, .black {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b648z1ve/3/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

CSS :

```
.header{
display:inline-flex;
width:100%;
}
```

HTML : add a container div

```
<div class="header">
<div class="green">
Latest News
</div>
<div class="black">
Some text here
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b648z1ve/5/